# Quantification of concentration from chromatogram paper

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna, experimental

In an experiment, I recently isolated and purified calf thymus DNA, hydrolyzed it with perchloric acid, and then applied the hydrolyzate to a Whatman paper in a polar solvent and let it run overnight.

I must now determine a way to quantify the concentration of each base, now separated based on polarity on the chromatogram. This **cannot** be the following method: Cutting the paper containing the base and putting it into an acid-containing flask, then measuring the absorbance, followed by Beer-Lambert's Law calculation for the concentration.

I would appreciate any ideas.